# C: Looping the big array efficiently

Tags: c

I have a master list integer array which has around 500 numbers. And, i have a set of 100 randomized number which has picked from the master list to find the missing numbers. Now, I need to go through this randomized number list against the master list. What would be the best approach in C programming to go through it without hanging the program. If i go through in simple 'for' loop for 500 elements, it will hang as it needs to go through the entire list. Could someone direct me on this?

Thanks.

Comment: if the list is not relate to UI, you can run the function in background thread..

Comment: Although it seems like if you are only doing this once, an array of 500 entries should not present any significant slowdown in your code.

Comment: Okay, just for example i gave 500, lets take 50,000 elements.

Comment: If you don't want it to make the UI unresponsive, you _have_ to do it in a separate thread. If you need to update the UI while doing the operation (updating a progress bar for example), then there are many ways of communication between threads, from advanced message queues to simply setting the properties UI elements directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should profile it. It's only 500*100=50,000 operations at the max we're talking about. An average modern computer is capable of finishing it off in under one-tenth of a second, unless you code it very inefficiently.

Assuming that you would like to optimize it anyway, you should sort the master array, and run a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) on it for each element of the randomized array. This would reduce the number of operations from 50,000 to at most 900, because a binary search of 500 numbers requires at most 9 comparisons.

Here is an implementation that uses built-in sorting and binary search functions ([`qsort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) and [`bsearch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/bsearch)) of the standard C library:

```
int less_int(const void* left, const void* right) {
    return *((const int*)left) - *((const int*)right);
}

int main(void) {
    size_t num_elements = 500;
    int* a = malloc(num_elements*sizeof(int));
    for(size_t i=0 ; i<num_elements ; i++) {
        a[i] = rand() % num_elements;
    }
    qsort(a, num_elements, sizeof(int), less_int);
    size_t num_rand = 100;
    int* r = malloc(num_rand*sizeof(int));
    for(size_t i=0 ; i < num_rand ; i++) {
        r[i] = rand() % num_rand;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0 ; i != num_rand ; i++) {
        int *p = (int*) bsearch (&r[i], a, num_elements, sizeof(int), less_int);
        if (p) {
            printf ("%d is in the array.\n", *p);
        } else {
            printf ("%d is not in the array.\n", r[i]);
        }
    }

    free(a);
    free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Here is a [link to this running program on ideone](http://ideone.com/01CDC).

Comment: Sort the randomised array and run binary search on it for every element in master array to find out missing elements?

Comment: I am sorry for the confusion, its not for iPhone, this is just C program.

Comment: @user1729070 Then it should be even less of a problem as a computer is faster than a phone. The thing here is to _profile_ and _measure_. Unless you need to do this several times a second it will most likely not be noticeable.

Comment: @SparKot Absolutely: as long as one array is sorted, you can use a binary search on elements of the other one, depending on what you are looking for.

Comment: Okay, the Master array is like this, int myArr[500] = {1, 2,3,...500}; and radom array would be int randArr[100] = {7, 45, 6, ...}.. i think i don't need to sort Master array here. Could you give me a sample, that would be help a lot and close it.

Comment: @user1729070 Wait, if the master array contains numbers `1` through `500`, why do you need an array in the first place?

Comment: Okay, i think i'm not able to give the right data as its being on internal program. Just for example i gave master array and random array values. I want to know the logic to be solved when such scenarios arise, and your binary search should solve this issue, i read it though.

Answer (score 1):

n - Randomised array length.

m - Masterlist array length.

1. Sort the randomised arrary. **n*log(n)**
2. Binary search in sorted array for every element in Master list. Hence you'll have every missing element. **(m)*log(n)**

=> **(m+n) * log(n)** for the whole operation. With **n=100** and **m=500** we've

**600 * log(100)** log to base 2

approx 3986 iterations compared to 50000 iteration with raw coding.

PS: If both arrays are sorted, just comparisons of O(m) should suffice.